# Card.io and Braintree Camera Unavailable Exception

Tags: android, braintree, card.io

When I go to debug my app with a device plugged in, I get this error:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lio/card/payment/CameraUnavailableException;
```

This error just began after adding card.io. From disabling dependencies in build.gradle, I believe that these two are the culprit.

Here are the dependencies in build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:1.+'
compile 'io.card:android-sdk:4.0.0'
```

Please note, I did not include all dependencies in the project.

Anyone have pointers on how to fix this issue?

**EDIT**

Ended up being Braintree SDK + Card.io SDK (previously I thought ZXing was the culprit). I verified this by creating a new application and only pulling in those two SDKs. Received the same error. When I turned off one or the other, the application ran without error.

Braintree is supposedly removing the Card.io SDK from their build within the next month, so I will just hold-off on implementing Card.io for that time.

Comment: Are you including the braintree sdk?  If so, there's already [an issue](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_android/issues/19) about this, which is about to be fixed any time now.

Comment: I had thought my issue was unrelated as the error was different. This time I created a new application to verify that you are correct in it being Card.io + Braintree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Braintree release 1.3.0 fixes this issue by removing card.io.

Comment: FYI in case someone runs into the same issue...I had to point to compile 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:1.3.0' rather than the 1.+ as specified above, otherwise it was still grabbing 1.2.7